# Unable to instantiate receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptio in API 27

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I have problem with `ParseBroadcastReceiver`. Everything worked OK, till we went to API 27. And now we are getting `java.lang.RuntimeException`, and app crashes every time when goes to sleep and after awakening a device. 
Bellow is my code.

And in my  Application class

```
public class PopeApp extends Application {
```

public void onCreate() {

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

      Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
        .applicationId(Defines.parseApplicationID)
        .clientKey(Defines.parseClientKey)
        .server(Defines.parseURL)
      .build()
    );
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            <action android:name="1" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
            <category android:name="com.MidCenturyMedia.Shopper.light" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: what does your gradle file show, for proguard and depencies used?

Comment: this is dependency in gradle file :     compile ('com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.18.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

Answer (score 0):

And this is Stack Trase :

```
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3290)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1715)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```